# Mod rewrite with variable

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to get this:

https://www.example.com/property/details/123456/3-bed-house-for-sale

to re-write to this:

https://www.example.com/property/details/?reference=123456

I have this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^property/details/(.*)$ ^property/details/?reference=$1 [NC,L]
```

This redirects ok:

```
https://www.example.com/property/details/123456/
```

However, this gives me a 404 error:

```
https://www.example.com/property/details/123456/3-bed-house-for-sale
```

How can I get both friendly urls to redirect?

Many thanks,

Neil.

Comment: try `RewriteRule ^property/details/(.*)$ /property/details/?reference=$1 [NC,L]`

Comment: No. It still does not pick up the "reference". It returns nothing.

Comment: @DusanBajic I have made edits to the question above.

Comment: Is reference value always an integer?

Comment: If reference value is always an integer, do `RewriteRule ^property/details/([0-9]+) /property/details/?reference=$1 [NC,L]`

Comment: If reference value can contain not only digits, do `RewriteRule ^property/details/([^/]+) /property/details/?reference=$1 [NC,L]`

Comment: It is ok with just the reference but anything trailing the reference gives me a `404` error. So, for example, this redirects ok `https://www.example.com/property/details/123456/` but this gives a 404 error `https://www.example.com/property/details/123456/three-bed-house-for-sale/`

Comment: Can you (just for testing) change `[NC,L]` to `[NC,L,R=302]`; after this URl in browser address bar will change to rewritten URl so you might be able to see what is wrong

Comment: If I do `[NC,L,R=302]` it redirects fine. If I just do `[NC,L]` I get a `404 Page does not exist` error.